# Multiple where queries, using orWhere, in fields of model and related models

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have many tables (user facing, not SQL) with filter boxes per column. The columns have not only the tables' fields but fields of related models.

I'm trying to add a feature where one can use a comma as an OR separator when filtering data. I need to do it generally as I have a rather large amount of tables, fields and relations. Plus some tables are built dynamically.

The code that adds the where clauses for the models own fields is this:

```
foreach ($filters as $column => $filter) {
    $q->where(function ($q) use ($filter, $model, $column) {
        $first = array_pop($filter);
        $q->where("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$first%");
        foreach ($filter as $or) {
            $q->orWhere("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$or%");
        }
    });
}
```

This works as expected. When trying to do the same thing with a relations fields the only difference is using whereHas and including the model:

```
foreach ($filters as $column => $filter) {
    $q->whereHas($model, function ($q) use ($filter, $model, $column) {
        $first = array_pop($filter);
        $q->where("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$first%");
        foreach ($filter as $or) {
            $q->orWhere("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$or%");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that if I filter on a relations fields it doesn't work as expected. I suspect it has to do with whereHas with a sub where/orWhere clause. This is the output I get

```
No filters:
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| Contact ID | Type (Field in contact SQL table) | Ecozone (Field in Ecozone SQL table) |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  Filter -> |                                   |                                      |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          1 | Manager                           | Bush                                 |
|          2 |                                   | Forest                               |
|          3 | Worker                            |                                      |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|

Single filter on current model (correct):
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| Contact ID | Type (Field in contact SQL table) | Ecozone (Field in Ecozone SQL table) |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  Filter -> | man                               |                                      |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          1 | Manager                           | Bush                                 |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|

Multiple filter on current model (correct):
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| Contact ID | Type (Field in contact SQL table) | Ecozone (Field in Ecozone SQL table) |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  Filter -> | man, wor                          |                                      |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          1 | Manager                           | Bush                                 |
|          3 | Worker                            |                                      |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|

Single filter on related model field (correct):
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| Contact ID | Type (Field in contact SQL table) | Ecozone (Field in Ecozone SQL table) |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  Filter -> |                                   | bus                                  |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          1 | Manager                           | Bush                                 |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|

Multiple filter on related model field (incorrect):
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
| Contact ID | Type (Field in contact SQL table) | Ecozone (Field in Ecozone SQL table) |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  Filter -> |                                   | bus,for                              |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
|          1 | Manager                           | Bush                                 |
|          2 |                                   | Forest                               |
|          3 | Worker                            |                                      |
|------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------|
```

The whole code path is below:

In controller:

```
return Contacts::with(
   'ecozone'
)->where( function ($q) {
    $this->set_filters($q, 'contact');
})->paginate($count);
```

In BaseController:

```
protected function set_filters($q, $current_model) {

    $filters_array = $this->parse_filters();

    if ($filters_array) {
        foreach($filters_array as $model => $filters) {
            if ($model == $current_model) {
                foreach($filters as $column => $filter) {
                    $q->where(function ($q) use ($filter, $model, $column) {
                        $first = array_pop($filter);
                        $q->where("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$first%");
                        foreach($filter as $or) {
                            $q->orWhere("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$or%");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                foreach($filters as $column => $filter) {
                    $q->whereHas($model, function ($q) use ($filter, $model, $column) {
                        $first = array_pop($filter);
                        $q->where("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$first%");
                        foreach($filter as $or) {
                            $q->orWhere("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$or%");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

$this->filters is:

```
protected function parse_filters() {
    $filters = Input::get('filters');
    $filters = json_decode($filters);

    $filters = array_where($filters, function($key, $value) {
        return !empty($value);
    });
    $filters = (Array) $filters;
    $has_filters = !empty($filters);

    if ($has_filters) {
        $filters_array = [];
        foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
            $value = explode(',', $value);
            array_set($filters_array, $key, $value);
        }
    } else {
        $filters_array = false;
    }

    return $filters_array;
}
```

And returns, what I think is correct, the following array. First level is model, second is field, third is comma separated OR clauses

```
Array (
    [ecozone] => Array
        (
            [ecozone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => bush
                    [1] => forest
                )

        )

    [contact] => Array
        (
            [contact_type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => manager
                    [1] => worker
                )

        )

)
```

A dump of the SQL being used when filtering on current model fields. This works as expected:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select count(*) as aggregate from `contact` where `contact`.`deleted_at` is null and ((`contact`.`physical_address` LIKE ? or `contact`.`physical_address` LIKE ?))' (length=163)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '%add%' (length=5)
          1 => string '%nana%' (length=6)
      'time' => float 1.67
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `contact` where `contact`.`deleted_at` is null and ((`contact`.`physical_address` LIKE ? or `contact`.`physical_address` LIKE ?)) limit 10 offset 0' (length=161)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '%add%' (length=5)
          1 => string '%nana%' (length=6)
      'time' => float 0.91
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `ecozone` where `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null and `ecozone`.`id` in (?, ?)' (length=89)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '2' (length=1)
      'time' => float 0.8
```

A SQL query dump of filtering by a related models fields. This doesn't work as expected:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select count(*) as aggregate from `contact` where `contact`.`deleted_at` is null and ((select count(*) from `ecozone` where `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null and `contact`.`ecozone_id` = `ecozone`.`id` and `ecozone`.`ecozone` LIKE ? or `ecozone`.`ecozone` LIKE ? and `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1)' (length=301)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '%grass%' (length=7)
          1 => string '%bush%' (length=6)
      'time' => float 1.18
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `contact` where `contact`.`deleted_at` is null and ((select count(*) from `ecozone` where `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null and `contact`.`ecozone_id` = `ecozone`.`id` and `ecozone`.`ecozone` LIKE ? or `ecozone`.`ecozone` LIKE ? and `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1) limit 10 offset 0' (length=299)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '%grass%' (length=7)
          1 => string '%bush%' (length=6)
      'time' => float 0.89
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `ecozone` where `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null and `ecozone`.`id` in (?, ?)' (length=89)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '2' (length=1)
      'time' => float 1.38
```

Comment: What does $this->parse_filters(); do? I don't see where the string gets split on the comma, but I'm assuming that's where. Can you print_r your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like this for all your sets of filters:

```
`where(function($q){$q->where()->orWhere();})`
```

to make those inner `wheres` wrapped in `(...)` because by adding simple `orWhere` you mess up whole query:

```
// your 2nd query in the incorrect array:
select * from `contact` where `contact`.`deleted_at` is null and
  ((select count(*) from `ecozone` where `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null 
    and `contact`.`ecozone_id` = `ecozone`.`id` 
    // this is your first where()
    and `ecozone`.`ecozone` LIKE ? 
    // and this is orWhere, which make the query wrong
    or `ecozone`.`ecozone` LIKE ? and `ecozone`.`deleted_at` is null)
  >= 1) limit 10 offset 0
```

You already did that for top level filters, but not in `whereHas`

---

So it should look like this:

```
} else {
    foreach($filters as $column => $filter) {
        $q->whereHas($model, function ($q) use ($filter, $model, $column) {
            $q->where(function ($q) use ($filter, $model, $column) {
               $first = array_pop($filter);
               $q->where("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$first%");
               foreach($filter as $or) {
                   $q->orWhere("$model.$column", 'LIKE', "%$or%");
               }
            });
        });
    }
}
```