# if and where not working in Laravel 5.2 model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a view where I have search form with a `city` select.
In controller I request it and send it to model, in order to get filetered results, but `if` statement doesn't work in model:

```
$query = DB::table('orders')...some where clauses etc...;//works
  if ($city_id) {
        $query->where('orders.location', '=', $city_id);
    }
return $query->paginate(15);
```

I checked it with `dd($city_id)` - it shows that requested value achieves Order model. But anyway in my controller Order model returns unfiltered results (checked with dd too).
How can I fix this?

Comment: Problem was with orWhere...
Resolved with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687811/multiple-where-queries-using-orwhere-in-fields-of-model-and-related-models